# Eclipse cant be opened on mac m1

Tags: eclipse, macos, apple-m1

I have installed eclipse aarch64 based on my mac m1.
it was working fine. later i stopped using it for few days but i was just opening and closing it just to make sure it is not crashing as it used to happen with x64 version.
Now even with aarch it is crashing.
As soon as i open it via launch pad it says 'The apllication 'Eclipse'can't be opened.

Here are the details of eclipse and jdk version that i am currently using.
Eclipse: eclipse-java-2021-12-R-macosx-cocoa-aarch64
Jdk: jdk-17_macos-aarch64_bin

Comment: That's the .dmg file, not the Eclipse Installer, right? You put the .dmg file where?

Comment: 'Ts right under my system's downloads folder

Comment: That's might be the issue.

Comment: where should be placing the .dmg?

Comment: Does dragging the .dmg file to your _Applications_ folder work?

Answer (score 15):

I've just had the same problem on the second launch of Eclipse from a fresh installation. The solution was to re-sign the app with an ad-hoc signature:

```
sudo codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/Eclipse.app
```

Comment: Have you tested this with all kinds of installations? Via Eclipse Installer and via a .dmg file? With all Eclipse IDE packages, each as x86_64 and AArch64? With different Eclipse versions? With different installation directories? Or do you assume it's the same and assume your answer applies to all kinds of installations? If yes, please say so and tell which one of those you have tested.

Comment: Worked for me!  M1 Monterey Eclipse Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0) aarch64

Comment: Worked for me as well with the same version commented above - seems to be a weird bug that needs reporting.

Comment: This worked for me on M1, os 12.2.1